# PHP:Keep variables/functions/session_start in one include file?

Tags: php, redirect

this may be a question without an answer but...

In classic ASP I used to have a wonderful include file at the top of each page.  Not only did it have the basic html template for the top of the page for every page on the site...it also had key variables like the dbase connection string, useful functions, and assorted variables that if changed would propagate through whole site.  I just had to include it at the top of every page of the site and it gave me uniform look and access to all sorts of stuff.  Best part... ASP let me do redirects below after html was sent in top include file, for example, upon a successful login, form submission or other action by user.

Now I'm learning PHP (still noob).  It seems there is no easy way to do redirects once html has been sent as header.php fails.  And certain things you want on every page like session_start() has to come before any html.  So I could put an html-free include at top of each page with common functions, strings, and calls like session_start at beginning.  But there doesn't seem to be easy way to keep nice html template for top if I want to do redirect based on certain conditions below, i.e. successful login.  I would put code before html and throw it all in top-include file if not for redirect issue.

Is there a best practice for keeping session start in first line of every page and having other code handy, using a common html template and still preserving ability to do redirects.

Otherwise, if redirect always has to be before any html sent, then html can't be included as single file at top of site but must be inserted below code and any redirects on every page...

Thanks for any suggestions on best practice from experienced PHP hands.

Comment: It sounds like your site has reached the point where you have a lot of presentation code (HTML) mixed with your business logic (PHP). While your issues are certainly solvable without much pain (though we can't help you much without seeing your actual code) you should consider separating the business logic out into organized classes and only having HTML in "view" or "template" files. This is called [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and is a very common best-practice.

Answer (score 0):

For the session_start issue, elsewhere on the board, I found two suggestions to check if session is started to avoid error msg upon starting when a session already exists.  The first is

```
if (session_id() === "") {
    session_start();
}
```

however it returns an error, expecting [ instead of {.  A second way

```
if(empty($_SESSION))
    session_start();
```

doesn't throw an error but returns 0 if empty.  So my plan is to put the session_start at the beginning of the header include but condition it with a test to check session is not already started... then put in logcheck code that redirects to login page unless you are already logged in or it is the join page.  Then I will put in a variable equal to the html for the top of the page.  This variable can then be echoed in any file that has the header include to start the output.  That way, I think, I've separated html from logic in pages to allow for redirects in logic.  For pages of site, they get the header include.  THen each page can do logic and produce a msg.  This msg can then be echoed after the top html is echoed.  Result: header includes session_start at beginning, a universal logcheck to govern access across site and the top html template.  Pages do their own logic and can do redirects.  Finally, they echo output.  Will see if it works..

Comment: ok, sorry to keep posting.  There seems to be different opinions if you can check status of session_start before calling it.  Some say if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
} is valid.  I gave 2 more examples above.  Others say you cannot check session until you call session_start().  I want to do the check to make sure not accidentally starting sessions on top of sessions.  Anyone have definitive answer?  Thx!

Comment: As a final note on what I did for anyone who comes across this, I created one php code file to insert at top of every page WITH NO WHITESPACES OR RETURNS as they will stop redirects.  In this file I stored the top html in a variable using the very useful heredocs wh.. Some people don't like it but it worked like a charm for me.  Then I called this variable when needed to start page output after the redirects..  Doesn't feel like best practice but led to reasonably well structured code.  No doubt classes and objects are better but this will do in meantime.

Answer (score 0):

The inability to send headers after sending content is a limitation of the HTTP protocol. ASP is using automatic output buffering, but PHP defaults to sending content as soon as you output it. You can turn on output buffering in PHP, read here:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

However, you should definitely look into MVC. This is the standard model for building web apps in ASP as well as PHP (and many others): http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller